Age rating of horror aspect in game
I want to add horror aspect to the game i made on unity to make the game less boring. However, after looking at several popular horror game, the age rating of these game is really high which means these game is not suitable for very young children. I don't want to increase my game age rating significantly just because of the horror aspect i add to the game, because i want to reach as wide audience as possible.
So my question is, how do i add horror aspect to my game without increasing the game age rating significantly ? i want to keep my game age rating suitable for very young children.
The only game i know that have horror aspect while having age rating suitable for very young children is Minecraft. Despite the possibility of depiction of blood using redstone wire, depiction of violence using invisible armor stand trick and floating entities trick, and the existance of horror enemy such as zombie, skeleton, pigmen, and enderman, Minecraft surprisingly have PEGI age rating of 7+ [1], which is very low. So this left me with a question: what horror aspect is suitable for 7+ age rating and what is not ?

Horror versus "surprising" (kids) and "fun" challenges they can solve (escape the gingerbread house).

There are multiple video game rating systems and their rating criteria vary. You mentioned PEGI - is that the system you're focusing on?

The first thing to consider is what elements of horror are you going to include and exclude?  Are the horror elements more physical or mental?  Is there a supernatural element, or is it just a basic slasher villain?
As you mentioned, blood is one of those things that will increase the age rating dramatically in pretty much any region.  Gore, such as severed body parts and organs, is another thing that can increase the age rating.  The threat of violence can also increase the age rating, especially if it is more realistic.
Another thing to consider is do you actually want to scare the player, or do you just want to be spooky?  Like, there are plenty of games that have supernatural entities like ghosts, zombies, vampires, etc., but they aren't actually trying to induce any dread on the player, just provide an atmosphere of otherworldliness.  For example, the Luigi's Mansion series, Minecraft, and Costume Quest are spooky, they're not trying to put the player in a state of terror, they're including obstacles by using common monster archetypes and being silly.  Games like Alien Isolation, Resident Evil, and Silent Hill are trying to create unease and discomfort.
There are also other things to avoid if you do want to avoid going up in age ratings, such as swearing, adult (sexual) situations, use of alcohol or drugs, and probably even mentions of suicide.  Unless the story your game has requires the inclusion of anything mentioned previously, I would steer clear of such things.
That also neatly segues nicely into my next point; what is the story or background of your game?  You may want to have a wide, younger audience even, but what if your game necessitates the use of some elements above?  You could end up either dumbing down your game's message by not including such, or even potentially ruining the characters and story by trying to avoid more mature subjects.  Yes, if you have to include one of the above mentioned elements, your game's age rating will go up, but I would say it is better than sacrificing the integrity of your ideas.
In conclusion, you need to ask yourself a few questions as to what you want in your game, what you need to tell the game's story (assuming it has one), and how important it is to get that lower age rating.  I hope this helps.
